# How to wait for fetch Promise result before module.exports?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, semantic-release

I'm writing a configuration for the semantic-release tool using the `release.config.js` file, which allows generating the configuration dynamically.

Now, I need to call several APIs during the loading process. I found that the best practice for calling APIs is to use `fetch().then()`.

My code (simplified) is the following:

```js
const config = {
  plugins: [
    // some plugins configurations here
  ]
}

if (/* some condition */) {
  fetch(
    // API1 URL and its params
  ).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
    return fetch(
      // API2 URL and its params including `data.field`
    )
  }).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
    return data.another_field
  }).then(function(value){
    if (/* condition using the `value` */) {
      // Prints correctly extracted `value` from the API2 call
      console.log("Detected value", value)
      config.plugins.push(/* Additional plugin */)
    }
  })
}

module.exports = config
```

The problem here is that in the end `semantic-release` doesn't load that additional plugin.
I don't have enough experience with modern NodeJS, so I'm struggling to understand, how to force it to `await` results from `fetch`.

I found that in recent Node versions it's possible to use top-level `await`, but simply adding `await` before `fetch` doesn't work for a reason that is unclear to me:

```
  await fetch(
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

So, what is the best way to just perform a couple of synchronous API calls, or await results of all the `fetch`es and `then`s before the `module.exports`?

Comment: With a CommonJS module, you cannot wait until an asynchronous operation is done to export its value.  It just isn't something a CommonJS module can do.  You can do so in an ESM module that uses `import` and `export` and supports top level `await`.  The usual work-around in the commonJS world is to export either a function that the caller can call to get a promise which they can then get the value from or to directly export a promise that the caller can use to get the value.

Answer (score -1):

my solution to this would be converting to using modules :

in your `package.json` file add `"type": "module",`

and then use async await instead of `.then()`

it will look something like this :

```js
// export.js
let plugins = []

 plugins.push(await fetch("http://google.com/"))

export default plugins
```

and in the import file

```js
import plugins from "./export.js";

console.log(plugins);
```

note: this may not exactly what u wanted but u can get it to work this way

Comment: I don't actually have a `package.json`, because I'm writing this configuration for using the tool with different projects, not only nodejs-based. So the only thing I can work with is that `release.config.js` which is later consumed by the tool.

Comment: then you can simply change the files extension to `.mjs` instead of `.js`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, because the tool is looking for `.js` or `.cjs` only :(